# Efficient ways to search for text in an android app

Tags: android, full-text-search

Say, I have a 100 text files (100kB each) and I'm interested in searching those files for strings/keywords entered by the user.

One way to do this would be to read them every single time and look for the entered string/keywords and I could implement that but it might be inefficient.

Since I know all the data before hand, are there any other better ways to do this?

Comment: Put them in a SQLite database in an FTS table. As a bonus, you get Google-ish search expressions (e.g., `dog OR puppy`).

Answer (score 1):

See example on google devs: 
 http://developer.android.com/training/search/search.html

They use memory only SQLite database with FTS table. But you could easily change this to persistent db (drop VIRTUAL when creating table).

Answer (score -1):

Press Ctrl+H . It will open search menu. Go to File Search and tick mark the things as per your need and the text which you want to search, write it into the containing text: portion. It will search for your text in the whole project.

Comment: the OP's question is about an "android app".